# Stripe Coupon code with one-time use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, stripe-payments

I have followed the stripe instructions to add coupons to my app. The coupons work great but I want to make a coupon that works all the time but can only be used once per user.

My coupon model

Coupon.rb

```
class Coupon
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_many :charges
  has_one :manager

  validates_presence_of :code, :discount_percent, :coupon_count, :description
  validates_uniqueness_of :code

  field :code, type: String
  field :discount_percent, type: Integer
  field :expires_at, type: Date
  field :coupon_count, type: Integer
  field :description, type: String


  def self.get(code)
    where(
      :code => (normalize_code(code)),
      :$and => [
        {
          :$or => [
            { :coupon_count.gte => 1  },
            { :coupon_count    => nil }
          ]
        }, {
          :$or => [
            { :expires_at.gte => Date.today },
            { :expires_at    => nil }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ).first
  end

  def apply_discount(amount)
    discount = amount * (self.discount_percent * 0.01)
    (amount - discount.to_i)
  end

  def discount_percent_human
    if discount_percent.present?
      discount_percent.to_s + '%'
    end
  end

  def generate_subscription_code(manager)
    # Random, unguessable number as a base20 string
    #  .reverse ensures we don't use first character (which may not take all values)
    raw_string = SecureRandom.random_number( 2**80 ).to_s( 20 ).reverse

    # Convert Ruby base 20 to better characters for user experience
    long_code = raw_string.tr( '0123456789abcdefghij', '234679QWERTYUPADFGHX' )

    # Format the code for printing
    short_code = long_code[0..3] + '-' + long_code[4..7] + '-' + long_code[8..11]
      self.code = short_code
      self.discount_percent = 100
      self.expires_at = DateTime.now + 1.year
      self.coupon_count = 120
      self.description = "#{manager.email} Annual Subscription"
    save
  end

  private

  def self.normalize_code(code)
    code.gsub(/ +/, '').upcase
  end

end
```

Here is my charges controller also

charges_controller.rb

```
class Managers::ChargesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_manager!

  def new
    @reportapproval = Reportapproval.find(params[:id])
    @manager = current_manager
    @amount = @reportapproval.manager_request_report_type
  end

  def create
    # Amount in cents
    @reportapproval = Reportapproval.find params[:reportapproval_id]
    @manager = current_manager
    @amount = @reportapproval.manager_request_report_type
    @final_amount = @amount

    @code = params[:couponCode]

    if !@code.blank?
      @coupon = Coupon.get(@code)

      if @coupon.nil?
        flash[:error] = 'Coupon code is not valid or expired.'
        redirect_to new_managers_charge_path(id: @reportapproval.id)
        return
      elsif @coupon.discount_percent == 100
        @reportapproval.report_paid = true
        @reportapproval.free_coupon_used = true
        @reportapproval.save!
        @coupon.coupon_count = @coupon.coupon_count - 1
        @coupon.save!
        redirect_to managers_dashboard_path, :notice => "You have successfully requested a pre-paid report from #{@reportapproval.tenant_last_name} with a 'No-Pay' coupon."
        return
      else
        @final_amount = @coupon.apply_discount(@amount.to_i)
        @discount_amount = (@amount.to_i - @final_amount.to_i)
      end

      if @coupon.present?
        charge_metadata = {
          :coupon_code => @coupon.code,
          :coupon_discount => @coupon.discount_percent_human
        }
      end
    end

    charge_metadata ||= {}

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => @manager.email,
      :card  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    stripe_charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      => @final_amount,
      :description => 'Manager Paid Report',
      :currency    => 'usd',
      :metadata    => charge_metadata
    )
    @charge = Charge.create!(amount: @final_amount, coupon: @coupon, stripe_id: stripe_charge.id)
    @reportapproval.report_paid = true
    @reportapproval.save!
    if @coupon.present?
      @coupon.coupon_count = @coupon.coupon_count - 1
      @coupon.save!
    else
      redirect_to managers_dashboard_path, :notice => "You have successfully requested a pre-paid report from #{@reportapproval.tenant_last_name}."
      return
    end

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to managers_charges_path
    end

end
```

How can I add the ability to check if the manager has used the coupon before and only allow them to use once?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd need to keep a local record of when this was used.  My recommendation is to actually decouple the idea that you should be building coupon codes that live inside of Stripe as Coupons and instead make coupon codes that live inside your business logic (eg. falldeal2017, etc.) that can be used and correspond to some "standard" coupon (eg. 25-percent-off, 100-percent-off, etc.) that lives inside of Stripe.  That way you can control the logic around how often they're used by adding some correlation in your db between customer id and the coupon.

Comment: Ahhh, I see that's a good idea.